# C# MAUI Problem with overlapping "ListViews"

Tags: c#, android, xaml, maui

I have problem with overlapping List Views. My xaml is organize to three parts "inputs" (Pickers & Entry), "button" (start calculations), outputs (two list views which print List of "Duct" class:

```
    public class Duct
    {
        public int? dimension { get; set; }
        public double crossSection { get; set; }
        public double? airSpeed { get; set; }
    }
```

On windows my app prints view list correctly.
[image]

But on android I get overlapping view lists.

[image]

When I scroll this view list I lost all outputs.

[image]

My List view xaml code looks like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EngineeringCalculator.VentilationCalculations"
             Title="Rectangle duct to round">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <!-- Grid with X and Y lenght of rectangular duct-->
        
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Picker Grid.Row="0" x:Name="XPicker" Title="Select X dimension"/>
            <Picker Grid.Row="1" x:Name="YPicker" Title="Select Y dimension"/>
        </Grid>
        <!-- Grid with manual entry -->
        <Grid Padding="10" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="AirEntry"
       Placeholder="Enter air flow in m3/h" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="m³/h" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <!-- Button to calculate the best round ducts -->
        
        <Button 
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Recalculate"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Recalculate rectangle duct to round"
                Clicked="OnGetEquivalentChannels"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        
        
    <ListView x:Name="RectangleDuct" Background="Transparent">
            <ListView.Header >

                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Input rectangle duct informations" FontAttributes="Bold" Background="Gray"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Dimension" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Cross Section" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Air speed" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding dimension, StringFormat='{0} &#x2205;'}"
                            />
                            <Label
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding crossSection, StringFormat='{0} m²'}"
                            />
                            <Label
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{Binding airSpeed, StringFormat='{0} m/s'}"
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
        <!-- Print list with 3 best round ducts-->
           
    <ListView  x:Name="RecalculatedDucts" Background="Transparent">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="RecalculateSummary" Grid.Row="0" Text="Equal round ducts" FontAttributes="Bold" Background="Gray"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Dimension" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Cross Section" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Air speed" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{Binding dimension, StringFormat='{0} &#x2205;'}"
                            />
                            <Label
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding crossSection, StringFormat='{0} m²'}"
                            />
                            <Label
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{Binding airSpeed, StringFormat='{0} m/s'}"
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

How can I fix this? I'm looking for method to have slider for full page on windows and android/ios.

Comment: what kind of layout container are they in?

Comment: @Jason in <VerticalStackLayout>

Comment: I updated the question. Now there is full xaml code.

Comment: the layout engine has no idea how "tall" each `ListView` should be.  You can either set an explicit height, or try using a `Grid` instead.  However, if I were you I'd try using a single `ListView` with grouping enabled to separate the two types of ducts.

Comment: @Jason Is it possible with two lists? Or I must add new parameter to the class and add all "Ducts" to one list? Could You send link to something similar or something else what will help me with this?

Comment: I gave you three suggestions for fixing the issue, only one of them involves using a single list

Comment: Yes I know thanks for this but You suggested building one ListView. I tried do this with my two duct lists but nothing works. Now I know that this method needs one list :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview#display-grouped-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the layout mechanism doesn't know how high the `ListView` needs to be at runtime.
Just as Jason mention, you can set an explicit height for the `ListView`.

Depending on your needs(`the data structure` and `presentation` of the items in the two lists), it is recommended that you use [Display grouped data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview#display-grouped-data) to display the data.
Large data sets can often become unwieldy when presented in a continually scrolling list. In this scenario, organizing the data into groups can improve the user experience by making it easier to navigate the data.

Data should be grouped before it can be displayed. This can be accomplished by creating a list of groups, where each group is a list of items. The list of groups should be an `IEnumerable<T>` collection, where T defines two pieces of data:

- A group name.
- An IEnumerable collection that defines the items belonging to the
  group.

For more information, you can check document: [Display grouped data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview#display-grouped-data).

**Note:**

And there is an official sample here, you can refer to it here: [.NET MAUI - ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/userinterface-listview/).
Please play attention to [GroupingPage.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/ListViewDemos/ListViewDemos/Views/GroupingPage.xaml) and [GroupedAnimalsViewModel.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/ListViewDemos/ListViewDemos/ViewModels/GroupedAnimalViewModel.cs).

**Besides**, you can also use [Display grouped data in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping) to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, yes! I had problem with refreshing listview. Today I workaround this by using ```ObservableCollection<DuctGroup>```